# How do I reference a file absolutely in php when I don't know the file structure of the server?

Tags: php

I'm not a PHP person: I have to create a global navigation partial for a simple website, but I have to reference it from but the root directory of the site as well as multiple subdirectories. So my question is, how do I create the links in my navigation partial that will work from any location?

I tried `dirname(__FILE__)` but that goes all the way back to the server root. I'm not sure what the directory structure of the server this is going to live on will look like, and I'd like to be able to develop locally as well.

What am I missing here?

**Update**
Thanks Orangepill, I needed `dir(__FILE__)` instead of `dirname`.

Comment: Can't you use relative paths like `"../file.php"`, etc?

Comment: dirname(__FILE__) is the path of the file containing the statement not the server root. __DIR__ points at the same location.

Comment: @Orangepill 1000 internet points to you good sir or madam!

Comment: @user1807510 1000 ... that more then I make in a week... at this rate I'll be internet rich in no time :)

Answer (score 0):

Typically the `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` let's you know what the path is to the root of your site. The `__FILE__` and `__DIR__` magic constants gives you the absolute file or directory path. To make an absolute path relative to your document root you'll need to remove the document_root from your absolute directory path e.g.

```
echo relativeToDocumentRootPath(__FILE__), "<br>", relativeToDocumentRootPath(__DIR__);

function relativeToDocumentRootPath($path) {
    $root = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];
    $relative;

    if (!empty($root) && 0 === strpos($path, $root)) {
        $relative = substr($path, strlen($root));
    }else{
        trigger_error('Could not create relative path due to the absence of $_SERVER[\'DOCUMENT_ROOT\']', E_WARNING);
        $relative = $path;
    }

    return $relative;
}
```